# Binding a select box to a Collection (with Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have the following problem. I have a form bean and in this bean is a list with objects.

```
List<SomeObjectForm> toDisplay;
```

Now i want map a html select to this list. Something like that:

```
<form:select id="inputGroupFields" path="templateKey" multiple="true"...
<form:select id="inputGroupFields" path="templateKey.id" multiple="true"...
```

And this dosnt work of course. Now i have tryed to add different custom Converter like:

```
myConv implements Converter<SomeObjectForm, String>
myConv extends StringToObject
```

And this also not work. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or there is a easier way to do that.

Some addional Infos: 
-->i'm using spring 3.0.5
-->all this happens during a web flow

regards and thanks,

WiPu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form select you can do like this.

```
<form:select items="${toDisplay}" itemLabel="id" itemValue="name"/>
```

What this does is it takes the you "toDisplay" list and put in the select box. the itemLabel="id" will go inside your SomeObjectForm class and get the id value using the getId method, similarly for the itemValue also. Try this.